# Using reflector, how do you find how an attribute is used in code?

Tags: c#, reflector

Is it possible to determine in Reflector or any other tool, how an attribute is being used? All I have are some classes with an attribute being applied, I would like to see the code (disassemble some assemblies) to see how it is being used.

JD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search the attributeclass in the tree, rightclick and 'Analyze'; there you can see where the member is being used.

Comment: Thanks Jan, the first time i tried that my assemblies were not added to reflector, so that explains why I did not get anything.